# custom post type single page template not working

Tags: posts, pages, templates, customization

I created a page portfolio and select template **Portfolio Template**
My portfolio page does not access the **template-portfolio.php** file. In which also includes **content-portfolio.php** in template parts folder. It accesses archive.php layout if change the col-lg-8 to col-lg-7 and remove any line of code its effect on the portfolio page. It does not access/display **template-portfolio.php** layout/view
This is **portfolio-post-type.php**

```
 <?php
// Register Portfolio Post Type
function portfolio_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'portfolios', 'Post Type General Name', 'portfolio' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'portfolio', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'portfolio' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Portfolio Archives', 'portfolio' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Portfolio Attributes', 'portfolio' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'portfolio' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View portfolios', 'portfolio' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'portfolio' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'portfolio' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'portfolio' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'portfolio' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'portfolio' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'portfolio' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'portfolio' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Portfolios list', 'portfolio' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Portfolios list navigation', 'portfolio' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter portfolios list', 'portfolio' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'portfolio', 'portfolio' ),
    'description'           => __( 'display company projects', 'portfolio' ),


    'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-portfolio',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_post_type', 0 );
```

This **template-portfolio.php**

```
get_header();
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="main" class="site-main col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="home-page-data">
    <?php
     $portfolio = new WP_Query('post_type'=> 'portfolio');

    while ($portfolio-> have_posts() ) :
        $portfolio->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div> 

<?php   endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>  
        </div>
    </div><!-- #main -->
    <div class="main-sidebar col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div>
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php

    get_footer();
```

This is **content-portfolio.php**

```
     <?php
    /**
     * Template part for displaying page content in template-portfolio.php
     *
     *
     * @package E_blog
     */

    ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


        <?php eblog_post_thumbnail(); ?>

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php
            the_content();

            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'eblog' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .e

ntry-content -->

    <?php if ( get_edit_post_link() ) : ?>
        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <?php
            edit_post_link(
                sprintf(
                    wp_kses(
                        /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                        __( 'Edit <span class="screen-reader-text">%s</span>', 'eblog' ),
                        array(
                            'span' => array(
                                'class' => array(),
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
                    get_the_title()
                ),
                '<span class="edit-link">',
                '</span>'
            );
            ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- #post-<?php the`_ID(); ?> -->`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). There is no `template-portfolio.php` template. It needs to be `archive-portfolio.php`.

Also, you should *not be using a custom query*<sup>*</sup>. Use the main query in your post type archive templates. WordPress already queries the correct posts for you.

So remove:

```
$portfolio = new WP_Query('post_type'=> 'portfolio');
```

And replace:

```
while ($portfolio-> have_posts() ) :
    $portfolio->the_post(); ?>
```

With:

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post(); ?>
```

Also, you're not actually using `content-portfolio.php` anywhere. You need to actually include it into the archive template. Somewhere between `while ( have_posts() ) :` and `endwhile;`:

```
get_template_part( 'path/to/content-portfolio' ); // Leave off the .php
```

<sup>*</sup>It seems like at least 50% of the questions posted here these days are caused by people incorrectly creating a new query when they should be using the main loop. I'd appreciate any insight into where people are learning to do this.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320862/media-field-not-displaying-the-image-on-or-getting-value-in-redux-framework-word

Comment: kindly check this